# Can't load external ruleref Microsoft Speech Grammar

Tags: grammar, speech, microsoft-speech-api

I'm using Microsoft Speech API to perform Voice Recognition.

Everything was fine until I use an external ruleref (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361619)

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="fr-FR" mode="voice" root="ruleCalendar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0">
  <rule id="ruleAddEvent">
    <item>Hello</item>
    <ruleref uri="#world" />
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

Works fine but if I replace ruleref by external file the recognizer loop on RecognizeCompleted event and seems to match anything.

```
    <ruleref uri="other.xml#world" />
```

- I tried to reference to a very simple file
- I tried to reference to cmnrules.cfg
- I tried setting an absolute path
- The file rise parsing error If I put error
- If I put wrong values in ruleref like other2.xml it still loop

The C#code is here l.75:
https://github.com/JpEncausse/WSRMacro/blob/master/WSRMacro/WSRMacro.cs

I think it do not find the file define by ruleref.

- Did it search in relative path ?
- Is there a way to set a default grammar directory ?

Comment: It seems to be a COMException: 0x80045024 A rule reference to an imported grammar that could not be resolved.

Comment: Found also this description: http://bliny.net/blog/post/SystemSpeechSpeechRecognizer-works-SpeechRecognitionEngine-doesnt.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [previous comment](http://bliny.net/blog/post/SystemSpeechSpeechRecognizer-works-SpeechRecognitionEngine-doesnt.aspx) it seems to be a known bug ...